# How to create non-modal Tk window "stack" in Mac?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to create a "stack" of Tk windows/dialogs such that the z-order of the windows remains always fixed. In this sense they would behave like stack of modal dialogs, but I need that user be able to interact with all windows (or at least with the lowest level window). The lower windows would be larger and the relevant parts would be accessible although there are other (smaller) windows staying on top.

In Windows and Linux I got it nicely working by making windows `transient`. tkinter code follows:

```
from tkinter import *

level0 = Tk()

level1 = Toplevel(level0)
level1.transient(level0)

level2 = Toplevel(level1)
level2.transient(level1)

level3 = Toplevel(level2)
level3.transient(level2)
```

In Mac OS X, `transient` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any ideas how to achieve this kind of stack in Mac?

Comment: Do these windows need to actually be independent, movable windows, or can you get by with a stack of frames? Z-order of windows isn't under the control of tkinter, it is a function of the window manager. If they need to be independent windows, do you want the window decorations (titlebar, borders)?

Comment: I want to achieve the impression of "stack", for this the stack of windows with standard decorations seems perfect. They don't have to be movable, though. I'm building an educational Python IDE, where this stack of windows represents call stack, each window representing a stack frame with steppable code inside. The only reason I can't use modal dialogs, is that the console is located in the lowermost window and it needs to be always accessible .